# calling method with list of subtype without casting

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting, subtype

The Call

```
List<SubClazz> subList1 = new List<SubClazz>();
List<SubClazz> subList2 = new List<SubClazz>();
FuzzyCompareCollection(subList1,subList2); //Compile Error
```

How i could do it

```
FuzzyCompareCollection(subList1.Cast<SuperClazz>().ToList(),subList2.Cast<SuperClazz>().ToList());
```

Method Definition

```
public static bool FuzzyCompareCollection<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) where T : SuperClazz
    {
        if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        Dictionary<string, SuperClazz> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, SuperClazz>();
        Dictionary<string, SuperClazz> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, SuperClazz>();
        foreach (T item in list1)
        {
            dict1[item.ID] = item; //ID is an attribute of SuperClazz
        }
        foreach (T item in list2)
        {
            dict2[item.ID] = item;
        }

        bool equals = true;
        foreach (string key in dict1.Keys)
        {
            try
            {
                equals = Util.ReflectiveEquals(dict1[key], dict2[key]);
                if (!equals)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return equals;
    }
```

I think i should be able to call the method without casting it so SuperClazz since the Lists contain SubTypes of SuperClazz.
But Is there a way? Or is it really not possible and if there is no way could you explain to me why this can't work?

Comment: Can you also post the definitions of SuperClazz and SubClazz? Or more specifically, how is the relationship between them defined?

Comment: Works perfectly fine with the method signature. Please post sample SubClazz and SuperClazz declarations. May be they you are missing an inheritance relation.

Comment: Is SubClazz extend SuperClazz? It should. When it does, the code compiles without errors.

Comment: Yes SubClazz is extending SuperClazz but i couldn't get it to compiling. But the question is answered, anyway thx for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `FuzzyCompareCollection` method to take parameters of type `IReadonlyList<T>` instead of `List<T>`. This will work because in contrast to `List<T>`, `IReadonlyList<T>` is covariant. This means that given `Sub` is a subtype of `Super`, `IReadonlyList<Sub>` is a subtype of `IReadonlyList<Super>` where as `List<Sub>` is NOT a subclass of `List<Super>`.

Comment: ty that helped. still can't understand how List<Sub> is no subtype of List<Super> but you already helped me =). i'll upvote you when i have enough credtis

Comment: List<Sub> cannot be a subtype of List<Super> because there are situations where a List<Sub> instance cannot behave as a List<Super> instance. Specifically if you have a method that takes a List<Super>, and calls the Add method on it, passing in a List<Sub> to this method would mean adding an instance of Super (that may or may not be an instance of Sub) to a List<Sub>, which is not allowed. This problem does not exist with IReadonlyList<T> because it is immutable (no Add method).

Answer (score 0):

The missing part is probably:

```
public class SubClazz : SuperClazz
```

Also you don't need the calls to the `Cast` and `ToList` methods.

Comment: SubClazz is implementing SuperClazz, and indeed you have to cast the list to the supertype otherwise you'll get an compile error